# Trying to display and update map markers using Leaflet JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet, arcgis, jsfiddle

I'm trying to display countdown timers until each of my markers disappear on my map. The markers disappear when their respective timers run out, but the timers themselves are not displaying below the markers themselves as they should. I checked the Developer Console and noticed there are a couple errors:

1. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
2. Uncaught ReferenceError: component is not defined
   This error count keeps increasing until it stops at a high number. I'm guessing this is when the particular timer runs out because after that number stops climbing the same error is logged again and the number starts from 1 and continues to climb.

   ```
   L.HtmlIcon = L.Icon.extend({options: {},

   initialize: function(options) {
       L.Util.setOptions(this, options);
   },

   createIcon: function() {
       //console.log("Adding pokemon");
       var div = document.createElement('div');
       div.innerHTML =
           '<div class="displaypokemon" data-pokeid="' + this.options.pokemonid  + '">' +
           '<div class="pokeimg">' +
           '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + pokemonPNG[this.options.pokemonid] + '" />' +
           '</div>' +
           '<div class="remainingtext" data-expire="' + this.options.expire + '"></div>' +
           '</div>';
       return div;
   },

   createShadow: function() {
       return null;
   }
   });

   var map;

   function deleteDespawnedPokemon() {
       var j;
       for (j in shownMarker) {
           var active = shownMarker[j].active;
           var expire = shownMarker[j].expire;
           var now = Date.now();
           if (active == true && expire <= now) {
               map.removeLayer(shownMarker[j].marker);
               shownMarker[j].active = false;
           }
       }
   }

   function createPokeIcon(pokemonid, timestamp) {
       return new L.HtmlIcon({
           pokemonid: pokemonid,
           expire: timestamp,
       });
   }

   function addPokemonToMap(spawn) {
       var j;
       var toAdd = true;
       if (spawn.expiration_timestamp_ms <= 0){
               spawn.expiration_timestamp_ms = Date.now() + 930000;
       }
       for (j in shownMarker) {
           if (shownMarker[j].id == spawn.encounter_id) {
               toAdd = false;
               break
           }
       }
       if (toAdd) {
           var cp = new L.LatLng(spawn.latitude, spawn.longitude);
           var pokeid = PokemonIdList[spawn.pokemon_id];
           var pokeMarker = new L.marker(cp, {
               icon: createPokeIcon(pokeid, spawn.expiration_timestamp_ms)
           });
           shownMarker.push({
               marker: pokeMarker,
               expire: spawn.expiration_timestamp_ms,
               id: spawn.encounter_id,
               active: true
           });
           map.addLayer(pokeMarker);
           pokeMarker.setLatLng(cp);
       }
   }


   //TODO:<--Timer Functions-->//
   function calculateRemainingTime(element) {
       var $element = $(element);
       var ts = ($element.data("expire") / 1000 | 0) - (Date.now() / 1000 | 0);
       var minutes = component(ts, 60) % 60,
           seconds = component(ts, 1) % 60;
       if (seconds < 10)
           seconds = '0' + seconds;
       $element.html(minutes + ":" + seconds);
   }

   function updateTime() {
       deleteDespawnedPokemon();
       $(".remainingtext, .remainingtext-tooltip").each(function() {
           calculateRemainingTime(this);
       });
   }
   setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
   //<--End of timer functions-->//
   ```

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/caffeinatedcoder/wwzqjovo/) for a full view of the situation.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

## Solution

#### Thanks to user T Kambi for pointing out the issue!

I forgot to include the `component()` function.

```
function component(x, v) {
    return Math.floor(x / v);
}
```

After including this all works as intended.

Comment: As the error indicate the `component` object in `calculateRemainingTime` is undefined. What object are you expecting? Also there is a code `document.getElementById("test2")` but no node in the HTML has the id **test2**

Comment: I'm expecting it to be all elements with the classes `.remainingtext & .remainingtext-tooltip`. `calculateRemainingTime(this)` is called from within the `updateTime()` function, which is supposed to be passing each of those elements (which is what `this` is for) to the `calculateRemainingTime` function. Shouldn't the way it's set up work or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: No I meant `var minutes = component(ts, 60) % 60,` what should the **component** be here? It looks like a function where is it?

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid. Completely forgot to include that function *headdesk* Adding that makes everything work as intended. That's for pointing that out!

Comment: And `test2` was for early testing, it isn't used in my final code.